# Images in svg file doesn't show up in Qt

Tags: qt, svg

I'm trying to display a svg image with Qt and it works well except that any image (.gif, .bmp, ...) in the svg image doesn't show up (lines, circles, texts works OK).

If I open the svg in firefox the image displays correctly.

I have put qgif4.dll in a folder imageformats and QtSvg4.dll besides the executable but to no avail.

I'm displaying the svg with the help of svgview.h/.cpp and I'm running on a WinXP machine (Qt version 4.7.2).

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are loading it via a `QIcon`, it should work without assistance.

If you are trying to load it using a `QPixmap` or `QImage` - you can't.  You have to use `QSvgRenderer` (or the [related classes](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtsvg.html)) in the `svg` module to rasterise the data.